# Using Mongoose Populate Virtuals on Arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Here is my `Follow` model

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let FollowSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  followers: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Card'
  }],
  following: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Card'
  }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Follow', FollowSchema);
```

Here's my `Card` model

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let CardSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String,
  likes: Number,
  createdById: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Card', CardSchema);
```

A typical `Follow` Model in DB will have something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f0eef155ee5a5897e1a66d"),
    "user" : ObjectId("59e3e617149f0a3f1281e849"),
    "following" : [
        ObjectId("59e21942ca5652efc4ca30ab"),
        ObjectId("59e13b2dca5652efc4ca2cf5")
    ]
}
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- To get all post from those you follow, find `user` in `Follow` model, and for each `ObjectId` in the `following` array, pull all documents from `Card` model, matching `createdById` field.

Using Mongoose Populate Virtuals, how do I do the schema relationship and populate query eventually?

Or, how would I go about creating and querying such a relationship with or without virtuals?

Comment: That's not how "virtuals" work. The intent of a "virtual" in this context is that **"instead"** of keeping an `Array` of those `"following"` you would create that field as the "virtual" and keep a reference to the `Follow` model `_id` on the `Card` model. Or are you actually asking "how to change the schema, for virtuals?".

Comment: @NeilLunn Will appreciate an example, as I feel like [I don't know what I'm doing](http://ghk.h-cdn.co/assets/cm/15/11/640x480/54ffe5266025c-dog1.jpg)

Comment: Plus, the models won't be linked by their `_id`s, rather by a field `createdById`